# OR operator wth multiple combinations

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use this code as OR operator with flask and sql alchemy.

```
.filter(
(Model.c != True, Model.d == None ) 
| 
(Model.c == True, Model.d != None ) 
)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

However it seems this syntax only works with one parameter. Something like works fine:

```
.filter((Model.a != X) | (Model.a == Y))
```

So my question is how can I add a filter condition to select the combination of the first sequence or the second.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is the filter rule you want to represent this way?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want to represent this: (Model.c != True and Model.d == None) or (Model.c == True and Model.d != None) in filter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only commas, you're using the `|` operator on two tuples, wich is unsupported.

You need to use SQLAlchemy `and_` function:

```py
from sqlalchemy import and_
filter(and_(x == 'a', y == 'b'))
```

Quick edit: you can chain it with, for exemple, `or_` to achieve something like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_
filter(
    or_(
        and_(x == 'a', y == 'b'),
        and_(x == 'c', y == 'd')
    )
)
```

Comment: Is it better with the last edit or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies with the comma you used. When you used the comma, python interprets your code as a tuple of booleans. You can't pass such tuples through or. you should connect the two conditions with a boolean operator like `and` `or` and `not`, to form a boolean answer that can be passed through the `or` operator

Comment: This doesn't work work for me. Please provide an example. You cant just add 'and' in SQL Alchemy